# Css is not workig for mpdf file and works fine for html

Tags: php, css

```
<?php 
$this->fontdata = array(
    "HelveticaNeue" => array(
    'R' => "HelveticaNeue.ttf",
    'B' => "HelveticaNeueBold.ttf",
    'I' => "HelveticaNeueItalic.ttf",
    'BI' => "HelveticaNeueBoldItalic.ttf",
     ),
 );
 ?>
<h6 style="margin-top: 8px;margin-bottom:8px;font-family:HelveticaNeue;">
    <small>Device Location :<b><?php echo $device_location; ?> </b></small>
</h6>
```

in html file device location appear bolt. But when i am converting the same page into m pdf device location is not appear bolt.

Comment: Try replacing <b> tag with <strong> tag

Comment: I tried with <strong> tag but <strong> tag is not working

Comment: Can you share the full code or live link in JSfiddle to look into?